# How can I access my containerized create-react-app if I bind a HOST to it?

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I need to bind a `HOST` to my React app on development so that I can proxy to other services in the cloud. Let's say the host is `local.myapp.example.com`.

I've been running my e2e tests by starting up a couple of containers including one with an instance of my React app and then making Puppeteer do requests to it. Up to this point, the app has been accessible through `localhost` just by exposing the port:

```
// docker-compose.e2e.yml
- ports:
  - 8080:3000 # app is running on 3000 inside the container.
```

Now that I've bound it to the `HOST` above, I cannot access the app inside the container. I have updated my laptop's `/etc/hosts` to have:

```
// /etc/hosts - laptop
0.0.0.0 local.myapp.example.com
```

With this, it works when I run the app in my laptop, but it doesn't when I run it inside the container

What am I missing?

### Update 1

If I go inside the container, I can run `curl local.myapp.example.com:3000` and it works.

From the other container (the one with Puppeteer) I don't know what URL to use to hit it. Before adding the HOST I would just use the name of the docker container like `http://frontend:3000`, but now I don't know, as the URL doesn't work

### Update 2

Here's my `docker-compose` file. I didn't mention it before because I didn't want to ask an overcomplicated question, but since I'm posting the docker-compose, might as well: the container is behind a reverse proxy:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/frontend.conf
    ports:
      - "9520:8080"

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.e2e
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: my.private.registry/user/backend:latest


// reverse proxy conf
server {
  listen 8080;

  location /api {
      proxy_pass         http://backend:3000/api;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location / {
      # proxy_pass         http://frontend:3000;
      proxy_pass         https://frontend:3000;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

From Chrome I used to hit `http://localhost:9520`. Now that I need to bind a `HOST` (and also I need `HTTPS=true` on my create-react-app), I need to hit `http://local.myapp.example.com:9520` from Chrome (not sure if https need to go here?).

From within the reverse proxy container, I can do `curl --insecure --header 'Host: local.myapp.example.com' https://frontend:3000` and it resolves.

From Chrome, I try to hit both `http` and `https` `local.myapp.example.com:9520` but it doesn't work.

From Postman, it works if I do `http://local.myapp.example.com:9520`

### Summary

I need to be able to hit `https://local.myapp.example.com:9520` from Chrome (or Puppeteer) on my laptop, it should go to the reverse proxy container on port `8080`. The reverse proxy then will `proxy_pass` it to the `frontend` container on port `3000`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, but if you are using docker-compose, [this might work](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts).

Comment: just for confirmation. When you access containerized application do you use this URL `http://local.myapp.example.com:8080`?

Comment: I currently don't know how to access the containerized one, since that URL doesn't work (@BukharovSergey)

Comment: @Tholle yes, using docker-compose

Comment: Could you please provide entire `docker-compose.e2e.yml` file?

Comment: @BukharovSergey I updated my question providing docker compose file

Comment: When you say "bind a `HOST`", what specifically are you doing?  What changes in this setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze create-react-app's webserver can [bind to a host](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#advanced-configuration) using a `HOST` env variable

Comment: I'd say with maybe 70% certainty that you need to not set `HOST`, and set up a DNS record for `local.myapp.example.com` that points at the host, and not touch `/etc/hosts`, and it'll work.  (Or if you _really_ don't have a DNS service then set `local.myapp.example.com` to point at the host's IP address in `/etc/hosts` on _every_ host you control; but definitely don't set any host name to resolve to 0.0.0.0.)  There's some mention of proxy requests in the question and the documentation that gives me some pause, though.